# Can I filter records I loop through in for loop? Python Template

Tags: html, django, templates, django-templates

Currently, I am using a for loop in my Django template like this:

```
{% for item in itemlist.items.all %}
   <!-- do something -->
{% endfor %}
```

Now this works great for looping through all records in my itemlist, but I would like to add a filter, for example let's say that my items have a price and I would like to only loop through the items where the price is >5. How can I achieve this? Is there a way to slice like there is with if statements?

I tried something like this but that didn't work"

```
{% for item in itemlist.items.all|price > 5 %}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your models.

Define a model method.

```
class ItemList(models.Model):
     field1 = models.CharField(...)

     def get_items(self):
          return self.items.filter(price__gt = 5)
```

In your template you can do something like this.

```
{% for item in itemlist.get_items %}
   <!-- do something -->
{% endfor %}
```